# Python Sphinx accessing the html_context from within conf.py

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a sphinx project with an [extension](https://holzhaus.github.io/sphinx-multiversion/master/context.html) that provides a set of values that can be accessed in the template files from the html_context.

I would like to make a slight modification depending on one of these extension provided variables inside of my conf.py file. The sphinx documentation only states how to provide more html_context values to the templates but not how to read out extension generated html_context values from within conf.py. Is there a good method to achieving this or are these values generated after conf.py has been read and executed?

Answer (score 0):

The `html_context` is filled in the main entrypoint, and it's passed to the `Sphinx` object as part of the `confoverrides`:

https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3d8fbd992cedf1784b106cf43ecbc452953ebe17/sphinx/cmd/build.py#L267-L277

which are then combined with the actual settings from `conf.py` to create the `Config` object:

https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3d8fbd992cedf1784b106cf43ecbc452953ebe17/sphinx/application.py#L216

Therefore, from my understanding, `conf.py` never sees this `html_context` and what you are asking can't be done.